# Showing Statistics for Multiple Attribute using 'Show Statistical Summary' tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics

I need on the fly statistic as I select point on canvas. What the tool does though is give you the statistic and the given value for the Attribute selected.
[image]

What if I need the value of multiples Attributes. let's say I want the sum of an attribute named Area, and of an other attribute named perimeter. I tried using the equation tool to concatenate the data like so:

> 'area:' || area || 'perimeter:' || perimeter

But that doesn't create a new column for new different attributes and now the value just comes back empty.

Comment: The statistics panel only works for one attribute at time. You could try the GroupStats plugin. https://anitagraser.com/2013/02/02/group-stats-tutorial/

Comment: that works, but I'd like something that would be more 'on the fly'. With this tool I'd have to click recalculate every time. and the result is kind of messy. I'm sure there is a way to update the show statistical summary tool to add more than one value.